# InputMismatchException occurred when inputing String and Double values

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

Here is my problem I've been struggling with:

I want the input to be in this form:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsiR6.png)

So I wrote the code like this. Unfortunately, it either gives me an InputMismatchException at line 6 or cannot break at "END_PRICES".

```
        Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> fruitName = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Double> fruitPrice = new ArrayList<>();
        while(true) {
            String str=input.next();
            Double v=input.nextDouble();
            if(str.equals("END_PRICES")) break;
            fruitName.add(str);
            fruitPrice.add(v);
            input.nextLine();
        }
```

Anyone knows how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Swap around the `Double` and `if` lines?

Comment: @Andy Turner Thanks, it works! Amazing!

Answer (score 0):

The condition in while loop can be changed to check first if there is a nextLine and then find contents of the line like this:

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()){
            String s = sc.nextLine();
            if (s.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("END_PRICES")){
                break;
            }
            String[] values = s.split(" ");
            double price = Double.parseDouble(values[1]);
            fruitName.add(values[0]);
            fruitPrice.add(price);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your way of thinking is much better than mine!